# Searching through a set

Tags: c++, iterator, traversal, set

I having a bit of difficulty trying to get through a set of strings. Methods used for vectors and arrays will not work here; I tried numerous ways trying traverse through a set, including calling an iterator but the compiler won't buy it. I've looked online but no answer seemed quite right.

Domain.h

```
#ifndef DOMAIN_H_
#define DOMAIN_H_
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class Domain {
public:
Domain();
virtual ~Domain();
void add(string added_domain);

    string toString();

private:
  set<string> the_domain;
  };

#endif /* DOMAIN_H_ */

Domain.cpp
    include "Domain.h"
    include <string>
    include <set>

Domain::Domain() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

Domain::~Domain() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

void Domain::add(string added_domain)
{
    the_domain.insert(added_domain);
}

string Domain::toString()
{
    // insert here
}
```

Hopefully I won't need to ask this again. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Of course you can use an iterator to traverse a set. How about you show the iterator code you tried and the error message instead of a bunch of empty stubs?

Comment: What's wrong with `find`?

Comment: *"Hopefully I won't need to ask this again"*.. Ask *what* again??

Answer (score 2):

```
bool Domain::searchForString(const string &str)
{
  return(the_domain.find(str) != the_domain.end());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use iterators:

```
std::set<std::string> strs;
for( std::set<std::string>::const_iterator it = strs.begin(); it != strs.end; ++i ) { 
   std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

You can use boost foreach:

```
std::set<std::string> strs;
BOOST_FOREACH( const std::string &str, strs ) {
   std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

you can use std::foreach

```
struct out { void operator()( const std::string &str ) { std::cout << str << std::endl; }
std::set<std::string> strs;
std::foreach( strs.begin(), strs.end(), out() );
```

you can use c++11 range loop:

```
std::set<std::string> strs;
for( const auto &str: strs ) {
   std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

You can use other std containers and not only them with the same code instead of std::set.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <sstream>

string Domain::toString() const {
    std::ostringstream ss;

    for (const auto& s : strs) {
        ss << s << std::endl;
    }

    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: `string toString()` probably shouldn't have anything to do with writing to the screen...

Comment: @MooingDuck Seems logical, changed it a bit.